# Codeigniter default controller don't redirect to members area when session is set

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm facing strange issue in Codeginiter 3. First I will post some code

```
class Front extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{

    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    if($logged_in){

        echo "still active";

         // $this->load->view('users/header');
         // $this->load->view('shared/homepage');
        // $this->load->view('users/footer'); etc..



    }else{

        echo "logged out";
         // $this->load->view('public/header');
         // $this->load->view('shared/homepage');
        // $this->load->view('public/footer'); etc..;

    }

}
```

}

I have Front controller which is default controller of my application and serves views for home page. These 2 views are different (they have different template parts, settings etc..) for public visitors and registered members.

So in code above I give pseudo code example how it looks  
**But! problem is**   while member is logged in still and he closes browser tab, or leave page (dont mean loggout)then again when visit site default controller loads home page for public visitor instead of home page for member who is still active.

Comment: Is your "sess_expiration" preference in the config set to 0? That would make it get destroyed when the browser closes.

Comment: no it is $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; by default setting

Comment: Is the user's browser set to clear history/cookies when the browser is closed?

Comment: It seems like a session and/or cookie config issue. Edit your answer and include your configs.

Comment: Did you set your session save path? Don't leave it NULL